# Is there a scripted way to configure Failed Request Tracing (FRT) and FRT rules

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-8

Is there a simple way to configure Failed Request Tracing (FRT) and rules in scripted way?

Apart from installing FRT as a feature, most of the solutions that I found are either manual via the `inetmgr` console or ends-up in cumbersome XML manipulation, like here: [IIS/ASP.net error for failed request tracing: "a failed request trace for this content already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474843/iis-asp-net-error-for-failed-request-tracing-a-failed-request-trace-for-this-c)

Of course the later could be probably scripted, but since it is a quite mature feature of IIS - I was wondering if this is covered already, so I don't need to reinvent the wheel to Add/Remove-FrtRules, etc..

Comment: The entire IIS configuration system can be manipulated via scripts (PowerShell scripts for example). However, there doesn't seem to be FRT related cmdlets, so you need to develop your own.

Answer (score 4):

I just needed the same and saw this unanswered question, then ended up creating a function for this with a simple use case of only adding status codes and time taken rules, but you can further extend it based on this sample.
Note: it's my first draft, but wanted to share

https://github.com/cjharmath/iisseven/blob/master/Enable-IISTracing.ps1

In case things change, let me paste some example here as well

Step 1) Enable IIS Failed Request Tracing on the site

```
$psPath = "IIS:\Sites\$SiteName"
Set-ItemProperty -PsPath $psPath -Name traceFailedRequestsLogging `
        -Value @{
        enabled     = $true
        directory   = "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles"
        maxLogFiles = 100

}
```

Step 2) Optionally clear existing policies

```
$pspath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$SiteName"
Clear-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests" -PSPath $pspath
```

Step 3) Add properties one by one with Add-WebConfigurationProperty and Set-WebConfigurationProperty

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $pspath `
        -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests" -name "." -value @{path = "$Path"}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $pspath `
        -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='$Path']/traceAreas" -name "." `
        -value @{provider = 'ASPNET'; areas = 'Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices'; verbosity = 'Verbose'}

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $pspath `
            -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='$Path']/failureDefinitions" `
-name "statusCodes" -value $FailureStatusCodes
```

Comment: Heya, quick question. I wanna just edit the ApplicationHost config and **NOT** the web.config, will your script suffice or does it need some adjustments? Step 2 and 3 seem easy enough to make use of the applicationhost config, I am just wondering about Step 1. Will that use Web Config or ApplicationHost.config?

Thanks!

Comment: The first is also using the applicationHost.config. Will edit the <site> section

Comment: Thanks for the code on GitHub. It contained a small bug where the parameter name was not FailureTimeTakenSeconds but FailureTimeTaken. I just submitted a pull request

Comment: Thanks for the fix @buckley! merged