# Cannot figure out how to Configure IIS Server level Failed Request Tracing Rules with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to be able to set the Parent level (Web server) Failed Request Tracing Rules with PowerShell.  We are automating the configuration of our web servers and this one has me completely stumped.  We want all sites to inherit this setting from the Parent.  Appreciate any suggestions.

I have tried the suggestions here [Is there a scripted way to configure Failed Request Tracing (FRT) and FRT rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547176/is-there-a-scripted-way-to-configure-failed-request-tracing-frt-and-frt-rules) but these modify the site's web.config.  Not what I am looking for although it is real nice!

[image: Server Level Failed Request Tracing Rules]

Answer (score 0):

Try this powershell script.

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests" -name "." -value @{path='*'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='ASP';verbosity='Verbose'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='ASPNET';areas='Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices';verbosity='Verbose'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='ISAPI Extension';verbosity='Verbose'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='WWW Server';areas='Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,ANCM';verbosity='Verbose'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/failureDefinitions" -name "statusCodes" -value "200-600"
```